# integrating m3db with graphite

Tags: docker, graphite

i am trying to integrate graphite with m3db database and for that i am using m3db docker image but is getting some errors while starting the docker. i ran the following commands :

```
docker pull quay.io/m3db/m3dbnode:latest

docker run -p 7201:7201 -p 7203:7203 -p 9000:9000 -p 9001:9001 -p 9002:9002 -p 9003:9003 -p 9004:9004 -p 2379:2379 --name m3db -v /root/m3db_data:/var/lib/m3db -v /root/m3dbnode/m3dbnode.yml:/etc/m3dbnode/m3dbnode.yml quay.io/m3db/m3dbnode:latest
```

but is getting the following error :

```
2020/02/18 09:38:51 Go Runtime version: go1.12.12
2020/02/18 09:38:51 Build Version:      v0.14.2
2020/02/18 09:38:51 Build Revision:     4e589d586
2020/02/18 09:38:51 Build Branch:       HEAD
2020/02/18 09:38:51 Build Date:         2019-10-25-03:39:26
2020/02/18 09:38:51 Build TimeUnix:     1571974766
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x1e0 pc=0x15984c7]

goroutine 1 [running]:
github.com/m3db/m3/src/cmd/services/m3dbnode/config.(*DBConfiguration).InitDefaultsAndValidate(0x0, 0xc000397210, 0xc0002e1978)
    /go/src/github.com/m3db/m3/src/cmd/services/m3dbnode/config/config.go:165 +0x37
github.com/m3db/m3/src/cmd/services/m3dbnode/config.(*Configuration).InitDefaultsAndValidate(...)
    /go/src/github.com/m3db/m3/src/cmd/services/m3dbnode/config/config.go:66
main.main()
    /go/src/github.com/m3db/m3/src/cmd/services/m3dbnode/main/main.go:62 +0x158
```

what can be the reason for this error?

Answer (score 0):

**Pre-requisite**:

*Installation kernal setup*

follow https://docs.m3db.io/operational_guide/kernel_configuration/ to set the parameters, like

- sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=3000000
- sysctl -w vm.swappiness=1
- sysctl -w fs.file-max=3000000
- sysctl -w fs.nr_open=3000000
- ulimit -n 3000000

**Installation and run**:

- `docker pull quay.io/m3db/m3dbnode:latest`
- `docker run --cap-add SYS_RESOURCE quay.io/m3/m3dbnode:latest`
- `docker run -p 7201:7201 -p 7203:7203 -p 9003:9003 --privileged  --name m3db -v $(pwd)/m3db_data:/var/lib/m3db quay.io/m3db/m3dbnode:latest`

Then open http://localhost:7201/api/v1/openapi to check that its running